# "е" и "ё" в метках

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, ё

В английском SO автоматически ассоциируются "widget" и "widgets". Следует ли русскому SO обрабатывать похожим образом букву ё?

Comment: пример некорректный: "виджет" и "виджеты", на мой взгляд более подходящий пример - "color" и "colour"

Comment: Но суть `-s` в том, что это происходит автоматически. Для color/colour наверняка что-то вручную добавили...

Comment: Все синонимы добавлены вручную, я просто указал что в вопросе рассматривается разное написание слов, а в примере - единственное и множественное число.

Comment: Думаю, что стоит считать «е» и «ё» одной буквой в названиях меток. Но я не могу придумать ни одного термина, содержащего «ё», который мог бы стать меткой.

Comment: Наиболее популярная метка с «ё» - [meta-tag:нытьё].

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: ах да, как же я мог забыть про нее.

Comment: Эм.. Вроде бы там не так работает?

Answer (score 5):

Да, конечно.

Можно прямо сейчас создавать необходимые синонимы меток, чтобы автоматически одно написание метки заменялось на канонический вариант.

То есть люди могут писать и «е» и «ё», а показываться будет только вариант с «ё».

Comment: @NickVolynkin: первое предложение в ответе выражает солидарность с feature-request. Второе говорит, можно не ждать, а использовать синонимы (меток с «ё» можно по пальцам пересчитать).

Comment: а, всё, я понял. ))