# Хаос в русских метках: грамматическое число, сокращения, и т.д

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Просьба модераторам и участникам с «толстой репой»: пройдитесь, пожалуйста, по т. н. меткам (tags), особенно русским (начинаются, в основном, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?page=69&tab=name)). Бросаются в глаза пары [браузер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80)—[браузеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b), <s>[база-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)—[бд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b4)</s>, а также нерусь [временная-зона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0), скалькированная с [англ. time zone](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q12143). Уверен, там такого довольно много. Уж [про е и ё](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/132/%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%91-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85) даже не напоминаю.

---

P.S. + ещё непоследовательная русификация, типа [network](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network)—[сеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c) и [encoding](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding)—[кодировка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Comment: База данных уже [синонимизирована](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/synonyms), многие другие метки — тоже.

Comment: В дополнение к комментарию @NickVolynkin, [многие метки в разном числе имеют синонимы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327/). Если у каких-то меток еще нет синонимов, пожалуйста, предложите их!

Comment: Возможно, с «бд» я не разглядел. Но вон вам ещё вдогонку безобразие.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, вместо «временно́й зоны» придумано лучшее определение?

Comment: @alexander barakin: Мы метки именуем на основе формальной грамматики/семантики или реально используемого русского языка?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, я не уверен, что при выборе названий меток имеет смысл вникать в столь тонкие материи.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin часовой пояс?

Comment: @PashaPash, насколько я знаю, понятие «часовой пояс» не полностью соответствует понятию «time zone». но в технические тонкости никогда не вникал.